# Creating a dymanic carousel with two items using Bootstrap and Laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm creating a carousel with two items per slide using Bootstrap and Laravel. However, I seem to be having trouble getting it to display properly. What is wrong with my code?

```
@if(!empty($products))
    <div class="product-details">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="productCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                @foreach($products as $index => $product)
                    @if($index == 0 || (($index%2)-1 == 0))
                        <div class="item {{ $index == 1 ? 'active' : '' }}">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                    @endif
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <p>This is an item</p>
                                    </div>
                    @if($index == count($products) || ($index%2 == 0))
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach

                <a data-slide="prev" href="#find-a-forklift" class="left carousel-control"><i class="tk icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a data-slide="next" href="#find-a-forklift" class="right carousel-control"><i class="tk icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest you clean your code a bit using Laravel Collection's method [chunk](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-chunk)

Comment: What would you suggest I do in this particular case?

Comment: @Cavefish As far as I see you are trying to use to items in a carousel so my suggestion is your code logic is too complex & may be unnecessary & you can use the chunk method to limit your code